# What database viewer to use for CouchDB?

Tags: database, couchdb, viewer

I'm pretty new to CouchDB. I have googled without finding a database viewer for CouchDB.
How do you view a CouchDB database without manipulating the raw HTTP messages ?

Ideally, the tool would meet the following requirements :

- Cross-platform (Windows or Linux mainly)
- Desktop application or Web application
- Allow editing of documents, databases etc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is built-in web application that allows you to manage CouchDB instance -- http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html#welcome

And your question is very ambiguous. You ask for the web application as option but without "a classic browser" you cannot use it.

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't find Futon very intuitive, please checkout [CouchDB Query Explorer](https://github.com/fahadmaq007/couchdb-query-explorer). The tool is aimed at providing an intuitive approach to configure & use. Define your own fields & filters. Querying is as simple as selecting one or more filters. For more information please visit [here](https://medium.com/@maqbool.ahmed.mca/https-medium-com-maqbool-ahmed-mca-couchdb-query-explorer-84887827e11)

## couchdb

Comment: It is better to attach the contents of the link briefly into your answer.